# git status выдаёт fatal:

Tags: git, config, git-push, git-status

Недавно впервые установил Git.
При вводе команды git status и появляется странное сообщение:

> fatal: bad boolean config value 'avto' for 'color.ui'

Видимо по этому не получается отправить Push.
Как это победить ?
Может кто подсказать ?

Comment: очевидно, что хотелось написать auto, а получилось avto. `git config --global color.ui false`

Comment: " хотелось написать auto, а получилось avto " - нет, я с git bash`а прям строку скопировал

Comment: имелось ввиду, что чуть раньше, настраивая свой гит, случайно или не очень была написана неправильно строка

Comment: Не получается найти галочку чтобы отметить комментарий как рабочий, но команда git config --global color.ui false действительно помогла

Answer (score 3, accepted):

очевидно, что хотелось написать auto, а получилось avto. Например, в процессе переписывания какого то туториала или запуска какой-то программы/скрипта для "крутой настройки". Но `git config --global color.ui false` должна вернуть все в норму. Можно попробовать и `git config --global color.ui true`